# SwiftUI - Timer to update text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm writing an application to get time based on timezone's, I'm unsure what's the proper way to keep time text up-to-date. It seems to lag because I'm using a `Timer` for updating every second. The example is pretty bland version of my project but close enough.

Also, I noticed the `Timer` may be interfering with my UI. If I have `navigationBarItems` such as a button, I can't click it *(must be when the timer is updating).* In main project.

Is there a better solution, something a little more elegant than using a `Timer`? I'm still new to `Swift`, so I have limitations.

[image]

```swift
extension String {
    func timezone(_ date: Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: self)
        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }
}

class TimerData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var date = Date()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init() {
        cancellable = Timer
            .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink(receiveValue: { [self] _ in
                self.date = Date()
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var timers = TimerData()
    @State var timezones = [TimeZone.current.identifier, "America/Halifax"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(timezones, id: \.self) { city in
                Text(city.timezone(Date()))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 15+? There is a really nice way to do it with that which is highly performant

Comment: @George unfortunately I’m not targeting iOS 15+. Strictly iOS 14 for now.

Comment: Ah, ok. If I do have a better iOS 14 solution, I'll add the iOS 15 with it for others in future. Running a timer publishing every seconds isn't _too_ bad, though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying only time from a Date object in Swift/SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004596/displaying-only-time-from-a-date-object-in-swift-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using SwiftUI formatting features vs using String

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
struct WorldTimerView: View {
    @StateObject var timers = TimerData()
    //Use TimeZone directly
    @State var timezones: [TimeZone] = [TimeZone.current, TimeZone(identifier: "America/Halifax")!]
        var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(timezones, id: \.self) { timeZone in
                    Text(timers.date, formatter: formatter)
                     //Inject the TimeZone to the Text
                    .environment(\.timeZone, timeZone)
                    
                    //You can also use style
                    Text(timers.date, style: .time).environment(\.timeZone, timeZone)
                }
            }
        
        }
    var formatter: DateFormatter{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss a"
        return dateFormatter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there appears to be an answer for doing this in iOS 14 now, I thought I'd add an iOS 15 answer for future readers. You could also make use of this with an `@available` check for iOS 15 users.

This way is highly performant, making use of [`TimelineView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview).

Example (`timezone` method taken from your question):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var timezones = [TimeZone.current.identifier, "America/Halifax"]

    var body: some View {
        TimelineView(.everyMinute) { context in
            List {
                ForEach(timezones, id: \.self) { city in
                    Text(city.timezone(context.date))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very efficient for iOS 15! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to update the view every second. Your text will only change once a minute, so you only need to know exactly when it will happen.

Let's say your `init` is called at 17:05:21. As you display on the screen "17:05", you need to change it to "17:06" only in 39 seconds.

You can easily compute this value from the current date by using `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)`

You might have delayed your publisher by this value, but in this case, the first launch will be a minute later than you expect. I'm not sure if it can be solved with Combine, but you can wait the first minute using a plain timer which it not gonna repeat.

p.s. If you need to get seconds, you can use same technique but waiting for 1 sec instead of 60. You still need to calculate how much time should pass to next second update using first timer before starting second one.

```
class TimerData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var date = Date()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    private let seconsInMinute: TimeInterval = 60

    init() {
        let timeUntilNextMinute = seconsInMinute - Date().timeIntervalSince1970.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: seconsInMinute)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeUntilNextMinute, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.fireTimer()
            self.cancellable = Timer
                .publish(every: self.seconsInMinute, on: .main, in: .common)
                .autoconnect()
                .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.fireTimer()
                })
        }
    }
    
    func fireTimer() {
        date = Date()
        NSLog("how accurate I am: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970.remainder(dividingBy: seconsInMinute))")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2021-08-27 17:38:00.001307+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0009131431579589844
2021-08-27 17:39:00.003226+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0030670166015625
2021-08-27 17:40:00.002219+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0021581649780273438
2021-08-27 17:41:00.000409+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0003418922424316406
2021-08-27 17:42:00.000471+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0003790855407714844
2021-08-27 17:42:59.999678+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: -0.000392913818359375
2021-08-27 17:43:59.998862+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: -0.001216888427734375
2021-08-27 17:44:59.997954+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: -0.0021028518676757812
2021-08-27 17:45:59.998144+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: -0.0019450187683105469
2021-08-27 17:46:59.997306+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: -0.002788066864013672
2021-08-27 17:48:00.000177+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.00012111663818359375
2021-08-27 17:49:00.003712+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0036530494689941406
2021-08-27 17:50:00.002929+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.002880096435546875
2021-08-27 17:51:00.001260+0700 SwiftUITest[57164:2936759] how accurate I am: 0.0011980533599853516
```

Also use `[self]` with blocks wisely. You only can use in cases when block will be called once and it'll happen soon, like `DispatchQueue.main.async` or `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)`.

In case with your block will return `TimerData` and never release it, so if you leave the screen there'll be a memory leak. In this case [weak self] is a must.

Comment: I'm confused what the outer timer is for, can you explain it a bit more please? Because it doesn't run every 60 seconds (which I can tell the inner one does). I assume you are trying to offset the timer's start so it starts _on_ the minute, but why use a timer? And when is the outer timer invalidated?

Comment: Nevermind, just realised the outer timer never repeats!

Comment: Philip seemed to have solved the issue for iOS 14 and another great answer for iOS 15+ Has been provided